# Using Composite Keys To Define "Dynamic" Relationship Types

Tags: database-design

#### The scenario

I'm working on a project that has pretty heavy relationship requirements. We have two competing ideas on how to approach the database design, and we're split on which one to use.

We have two types of entities, pet and adult. We are recording the common columns in a "master" table called `Organism`, and the columns only applicable to pets and adults are in their respective tables, `Pet` and `Adult`.

The issue is how to relate them, as well as defining relationship type. If it was just a matter of relating pet to adults, this would be simple: a "bridge" table between the two. The complexity comes in where we have to also relate pet to pet and adult to adult. We might need to say one adult is the spouse to another adult, or the pet sitter to another adult. We may need to say two pets live together, or don't live together but are blood related. We may need to later add other tables like `Vet` where we relate both `Pet` and `Adult` tables to as well.

#### Idea no. 1

So the first idea is that for each type of relationship we add in a "bridge" table, so one between `Pet` and `Adult`, and to relate `Pet` to `Pet` we would have a "bridge" table that relates `Pet` to `Organism`, and another "bridge" table to relate `Adult` to `Organism`.

If we later added `Vet`, we would need to add a "bridge" table between it and `Adult` as well as between `Vet` and `Pet`, and continue adding more "bridge" tables for each new relationship.

#### Idea no. 2

The other idea is to create a "dynamic" `relationship` table that has composite keys for both primary and foreign keys, so:

```
PrimaryID    PrimarySource  Relationship  ForeignID    ForeignSource
---------    -------------  ------------  ---------    -------------
1            Adult          Pet Sitter    4            Pet
2            Adult          Spouse        10           Adult
42           Pet            Blood Sibling 76           Pet
```

The "source" columns determine what tables the relationships are from, and can scale up so that any additional relationships are easy to make.

#### Considerations

The first option from what I'm told is more standard but the people against the second method can't seem to come up with any practical reason why this design would fail. I am interested in the practical application here, and what issues could arise in the two systems, if any. Is there a clear right answer here, and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationships can be simplified as

```
Entity <---Realtionship---> Entity
```

Like this

```
create table entity (id, entity_type /** etc **/)
create table relation (id, from_id, to_id, relation_type_id)
create table relation_type (id, name)
```

Pet/owner would then be

```
Entity(1, 'Dog') 
Entity(2, 'Person')
Relation(n, 1, 2, 'Owner')
```

This concept also accomodates shared ownership, i.e. a dog owned by two people:

```
create table relation(id, from_id, to_id, relation_type_id, share)
Entity(3, 'Person')
Relation(n, 1, 2, 'Owner', 50.0)
Relation(n, 1, 3, 'Owner', 50.0)
```

You should of course create constrains/checks to ensure that share is always 100 etc.

If you need to enforce business rules, for example *A pet can only be owned by a person, and a person can not be owned by anybody*

```
create table allowed_relations(from_entity_type_id, to_entity_type_id, type_id)
```

In order to enforce this you will need to create a trigger on the     relation table and check if the proposed relation matches the allowed_relations table. If the number of business rules is small (and seldom changes), the rules can be hardcoded as a check constraint on the relation table.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm the original poster, I thought I was signed in but I was mistaken. I'll be honest, what you proposed was my first attempt to solve the problem. One of our DBAs is insisting this "isn't standard" and "not part of any database theory". He also insists that this will be inefficient for a large environment as it will frequently require the entity table to be locked, which is why I switched over to the composite key method. Could you speak to these concerns in any way?

Comment: First, as someone who's been working with databases for almost 30 years: "isn't standard" is something worth noting as a concern - but should not stop you from proceeding. "Not part of any database theory" isn't an argument I'd ever use, under any circumstance. Now - Frequent locking of the `entity` table is potentially a matter of concern. However, beyond an initial population, I suspect that it will be used more in reads than in writes - in which case, locks would usually be able to be shared amongst readers, and wouldn't be a huge problem.

Comment: @RDFozz Would you say the proposed solution is or is not standard?

Comment: I believe I've seen similar things, though I can recall having implemented any. My concern for your original solution is that the foreign key relationship cannot be maintained using the built-in `FOREIGN KEY` mechanisms. Since both of the identifying keys could belong to multiple tables, everything has to be maintained via constraints (or, more likely, triggers). Which is entirely doable - but is not necessarily easy, and could have issues that aren't easy to notice until it's too late.

Comment: This solution avoids that by having everything in one table, but, there will presumably still be owner, pet, vet, etc. tables, as the fields needed for a person would be notably different than those for a pet. Queries become more complicated by needing to join across more tables - but that's not necessarily an issue. I would have explicit `person_id`, `pet_id`, `vet_id`, etc. columns in `entity` (or you're back to maintain some foreign keys "manually"); but, this can actually work as a substitute for the entity_type value (or a means to compute it).

Comment: That was actually the secondary solution @RDFozz, which I came up with to fix the alleged problem with Entity being locked. But if we used the solution matiasf proposed, where the bridge table relates Entity to Entity. Could you maintain it using the build in FOREIGN KEY mechanisms that way?

Comment: I suppose I would still say it's not a standard solution, but in the same way that Worchestershire Sauce is not a standard condiment at McDonald's - just because it's not standard doesn't mean there's anything wrong with it. I suspect that whatever solution you implement will be one you'll want to carefully document, carefully test, and will need to explicitly train new DB technical people on.